# CodeIgniter - Binding a EXIST subquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

First of all I'm new to the framework. Check the query I'm trying to transcript using the CI database object.

```
$where = "(".$this->tbl.".invoiceNumber = '".substr($searchFor,3)."' 
          OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM op_orders_products WHERE idProduct = ".(is_numeric(substr($searchFor,3)) ? substr($searchFor,3) : '-1')." 
          AND idOrder = ".$this->tbl.".id)
       )";
```

Should I do a separate subquery? Would like to make it all in one.

This is how I started. I wanna make sure the variables are binded and not passed as strings as in the original query.

```
$this->db->group_start()
           ->where($this->tbl.".invoiceNumber", substr($searchFor, 3))
           ->or_group_start()
             // I'm missing this EXISTS select subquery
           ->group_end()
         ->group_end()
```

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no EXISTS equivalent in Codeigniter's Query Builder Class that I'm aware of. So I'd just write it like this:

```
$this->db->group_start()
             ->where($where)
         ->group_end()
```

see documentation [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)

**[binding:](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#query-bindings)**

with CodeIgniter you can bind variables to your query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE a= ? AND b= ?";
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($a,$b));
```

This binds variables $a and $b to the corresponding positions (?) inside the query string.

**[escaping](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#escaping-queries)**

```
$this->db->escape()
```

this function escapes string data and adds single quotes around it.

Comment: Hi Vickel, for security reasons I wanna bind my variables in the $where clause.